# POST don't work on select

Tags: php, html

I have this modal and I want to get the 'select' value with $_POST['select'] in my link when pushing on the button, but it don't works (there is no id in the link), thanks you.

```
  <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Afficher les factures d'un dossier</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <center>
                    <?php

                     $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=MYHOST;dbname=MYDBNAME', 'MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD');
        $dossier = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM dossiers ORDER BY id DESC');

                     ?>
                  <p>Choisir un dossier : <form method="POST" action=""> 
                      <select name="select"> <?php  
                      while($d = $dossier->fetch())
                      { 

                      ?>

                          <option value="<?= $d['id'] ?>"><?= $d['id_dossier'] ?></option> 

                     <?php
                      }
                  ?></select>
                  </form>
                  </p>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a type="submit" class="btn btn-default" href="displayfolder.ph

p?id=<?= $_POST['select'] ?>">Afficher</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: you have a type , i guess  p?id=<?= $_POST['select'] ?>">Afficher</a>

Comment: `$_POST['select']` will only start existing *after* you POST anythig. So, why should it be there before?

Comment: Where I have to place it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to echo that fetch variable  like `<?php echo $d['id']; ?>`

try this `<a href="displayfolder.php?id=<?php echo $_POST['select']; ?>" ></a>`

I suggest you to use correct tags=> `<?php ?>` instead of using short tags=> `<? ?>` in php syntax. Otherwise go to php.ini and check this line `short_tags=on` or not.